# How to use " 9-sliced" image type in non-GUI elements?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

In my game, I am using simple textures on quads. I could see Unity GUI allows us to slice the image by setting "image type" option as **sliced**.

I would like to do the same to my other textures I use in quads.

In simple words, I dont want the edges of my textures to be scaled when the texture itself is scaled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have to generate the mesh yourself, not so hard as it sounds. The mesh has to look like this:

[image: 9 slice on a quad]

Each textured mesh is defined by vertices (red dots on the picture) and (in this case) each vertex has two parameters:

1. A `Vector3` with position. Only `x` and `y` used here, as a quad is flat (so, `z` = 0).
2. A `Vector2` with the UV, that is how the material is put on the mesh. This are the texture coordinates: `u` and `v`.

To configure this mesh, I added parameters:

`b` - for border - how big is the border of the gameobject (in 3d units)
 `w`, `h` - for width and height of the gameobject (in 3d units)
 `m` - how big is the margin in the image (in float 0f to 0.5f)

*How to do this in Unity3d:*

1. Create an GameObject, add a `MeshRenderer` with the material you want and an empty `MeshFilter`.
2. Add a script that creates a mesh. Look at [Unity3d docs for `Mesh`, first example](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html).

Note that for unity3d you have to create this with triangles, not quads (so for each quad make two triangles).

Comment: Thank you Chanibal! It worked for me. There were some small errors:
- At the bottom, you wrote v instead of u in every column but the first one. It should be: u=0, u=m, u=1-m, u =1.
- You never actually used the h variable. The y value for the 2nd and 3rd row should be: y=h-b and y=h.

Answer (score 5):

Chanibal's solutions worked like a charm for me, but since I wasn't an expert in the matter, it wasn't trivial to me to implement this. I will let this code here in case somebody could find it useful.

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class SlicedMesh : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _b = 0.1f;
    public float Border
    {
        get
        {
            return _b;
        }
        set
        {
            _b = value;
            CreateSlicedMesh();
        }
    }

    private float _w = 1.0f;
    public float Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _w;
        }
        set
        {
            _w = value;
            CreateSlicedMesh();
        }
    }

    private float _h = 1.0f;
    public float Height
    {
        get
        {
            return _h;
        }
        set
        {
            _h = value;
            CreateSlicedMesh();
        }
    }

    private float _m = 0.4f;
    public float Margin
    {
        get
        {
            return _m;
        }
        set
        {
            _m = value;
            CreateSlicedMesh();
        }
    }

    void Start() 
    {

        CreateSlicedMesh();
    }

    void CreateSlicedMesh()
    {
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(_b, 0, 0), new Vector3(_w-_b, 0, 0), new Vector3(_w, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(0, _b, 0), new Vector3(_b, _b, 0), new Vector3(_w-_b, _b, 0), new Vector3(_w, _b, 0),
            new Vector3(0, _h-_b, 0), new Vector3(_b, _h-_b, 0), new Vector3(_w-_b, _h-_b, 0), new Vector3(_w, _h-_b, 0),
            new Vector3(0, _h, 0), new Vector3(_b, _h, 0), new Vector3(_w-_b, _h, 0), new Vector3(_w, _h, 0)
        };

        mesh.uv = new Vector2[] {
            new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(_m, 0), new Vector2(1-_m, 0), new Vector2(1, 0),
            new Vector2(0, _m), new Vector2(_m, _m), new Vector2(1-_m, _m), new Vector2(1, _m),
            new Vector2(0, 1-_m), new Vector2(_m, 1-_m), new Vector2(1-_m, 1-_m), new Vector2(1, 1-_m),
            new Vector2(0, 1), new Vector2(_m, 1), new Vector2(1-_m, 1), new Vector2(1, 1)
        };

        mesh.triangles = new int[] {
            0, 4, 5,
            0, 5, 1,
            1, 5, 6,
            1, 6, 2,
            2, 6, 7,
            2, 7, 3,
            4, 8, 9,
            4, 9, 5, 
            5, 9, 10,
            5, 10, 6,
            6, 10, 11,
            6, 11, 7,
            8, 12, 13,
            8, 13, 9,
            9, 13, 14,
            9, 14, 10,
            10, 14, 15,
            10, 15, 11
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but remember to `mesh.RecalculateBounds()` after setting the triangles! I would also add `[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]` before the class declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another impementation of the same mesh as described above(just add Tile9Mesh script to empty GameObject and it should work 
[image: Screen of usage in Unity]):

```c#
using UnityEngine;

namespace Util {
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer), typeof(MeshFilter))]
    public class Tile9Mesh : MonoBehaviour {

        public float width = 1;
        public float height = 1;

        [Range(0, 0.5f)]
        public float uvLeft = 0.2f;
        [Range(0, 0.5f)]
        public float uvRight = 0.2f;
        [Range(0, 0.5f)]
        public float uvTop = 0.2f;
        [Range(0, 0.5f)]
        public float uvBottom = 0.2f;
        public float uvToWorldScaleX = 1;
        public float uvToWorldScaleY = 1;

        private Mesh mesh;

        private Vector3[] vertices;
        private Vector2[] uv;

        private void Start() {
            vertices = new Vector3[16];
            uv = new Vector2[16];

            mesh = new Mesh {
                name = "Tile9Mesh"
            };
            FillGeometry();
            FillMesh();
            mesh.triangles = new[] {
                0, 1, 12, 0, 12, 11,
                1, 2, 13, 1, 13, 12,
                2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 13,
                13, 4, 5, 13, 5, 14,
                14, 5, 6, 14, 6, 7,
                15, 14, 7, 15, 7, 8,
                10, 15, 8, 10, 8, 9,
                11, 12, 15, 11, 15, 10,
                12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15
            };
            RecalculateMesh();

            gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        }

        public void UpdateMesh() {
            if (mesh != null) {
                FillGeometry();
                FillMesh();
                mesh.RecalculateBounds();
                mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            }
        }

        private void FillGeometry() {
            {
                float w = width;
                float h = height;
                float l = uvLeft * uvToWorldScaleX;
                float r = width - uvRight * uvToWorldScaleX;
                float t = height - uvTop * uvToWorldScaleY;
                float b = uvBottom * uvToWorldScaleY;
                vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                vertices[1] = new Vector3(0, b, 0);
                vertices[2] = new Vector3(0, t, 0);
                vertices[3] = new Vector3(0, h, 0);
                vertices[4] = new Vector3(l, h, 0);
                vertices[5] = new Vector3(r, h, 0);
                vertices[6] = new Vector3(w, h, 0);
                vertices[7] = new Vector3(w, t, 0);
                vertices[8] = new Vector3(w, b, 0);
                vertices[9] = new Vector3(w, 0, 0);
                vertices[10] = new Vector3(r, 0, 0);
                vertices[11] = new Vector3(l, 0, 0);
                vertices[12] = new Vector3(l, b, 0);
                vertices[13] = new Vector3(l, t, 0);
                vertices[14] = new Vector3(r, t, 0);
                vertices[15] = new Vector3(r, b, 0);
            }
            {
                const float w = 1;
                const float h = 1;
                float l = uvLeft;
                float r = 1 - uvRight;
                float t = 1 - uvTop;
                float b = uvBottom;
                uv[0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
                uv[1] = new Vector2(0, b);
                uv[2] = new Vector2(0, t);
                uv[3] = new Vector2(0, h);
                uv[4] = new Vector2(l, h);
                uv[5] = new Vector2(r, h);
                uv[6] = new Vector2(w, h);
                uv[7] = new Vector2(w, t);
                uv[8] = new Vector2(w, b);
                uv[9] = new Vector2(w, 0);
                uv[10] = new Vector2(r, 0);
                uv[11] = new Vector2(l, 0);
                uv[12] = new Vector2(l, b);
                uv[13] = new Vector2(l, t);
                uv[14] = new Vector2(r, t);
                uv[15] = new Vector2(r, b);
            }
        }

        private void FillMesh() {
            mesh.vertices = vertices;
            mesh.uv = uv;
        }

        private void RecalculateMesh() {
            mesh.RecalculateBounds();
            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        private void OnValidate() {
            if (mesh != null) {
                UpdateMesh();
            }
        }
#endif


    }
}
```